# Failed to deserialize script metadata extracted for initialization script 'C:\Users\print\AppData\Local\Temp\ijtestinit.gradle' > C:\Users\print\.grad

Tags: serialization, metadata

Failed to deserialize script metadata extracted for initialization script 'C:\Users\print\AppData\Local\Temp\ijtestinit.gradle'

> C:\Users\print.gradle\caches\8.0\scripts\55xg0pokxwcazmeuswn4nqze\metadata\metadata.bin (The system cannot find the file specified)

cannot proceed further

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.